# PHP excute Python SFTP script

Tags: php, python

in PHP I need to do some SFTP, but I am having issues because I am not allowed to install the SSH extension, and phpseclib is not working how I need it to.

As such, I am going to execute a Python script to do the SFTP for me.  What I imaging is doing something like the following

```
exec("SFTPUpload.py remoteFile serverLocation");
```

So I execute SFTPUpload.py passing it the location of the file on my server which needs transferring, and the location on the server it needs transferring too.

In terms of the Python script (I am not too familiar with Python), I imagine it would be something like the following

```
username='sftpUser'
password='sftpPassword'
port=22


#SFTP
client.load_system_host_keys()
print " hostname =%s \n username=%s \n password=%s \n" (hostname,username,password)
t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port)) 
t.connect(username=username,password=password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
sftp.put(source,destination)
sftp.close()
t.close()
```

However, the way I am calling it from PHP, I need the Python to be in a class or something so I can pass it the variables.

How would I achieve something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do it with the `exec()` function as you described by simply parsing the command line parameters in Python.

Like:

```
import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

Where you can access the elements in `sys.argv` like a list.

(You could also take a look at the [getopt module](https://pymotw.com/2/getopt/) which offers even more (C-like) parameter passing options, but I believe the above solution will do.)

If the `exec()` function does not work, I believe you could consider to use the [system function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) in PHP:

Something like this:

```
$mystring = system('SFTPUpload.py remoteFile serverLocation', $retval);
```

Comment: Thanks.  How would I turn the script I have into a class that can take variables?

Comment: Why would you need a class? Normally you only introduce classes when you want to keep track of a state of your object. For your code this doesn't seem necessary. Also by variables you mean parameters that you want to pass to the script? Since that's being done by parsing the command line parameters like I described ;)